# Game of Thrones: ship rules

Tags: game-of-thrones

It's really not clear to us how ships work in Game of Thrones

- Can you use a ship (an empty one, not carrying land units) to attack a castle/fortress/territory/port?
- What happens if you attack such areas with ships and those areas are defended by land units?
- If you have ships in a port and the connected castle is conquered, what happens to the ships?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From the [rulebook](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/agot-bg-2nd-ed/support/VA65_AGoT2_Rulebook_web.pdf):

1. **No.** "Ship units may move into friendly connected port areas or into adjacent sea areas, but may never move into a land area." (p. 15) So a ship alone cannot attack or conquer land. It can support a land attack, though, although the reverse is not true (p. 18).
2. As indicated above, **this cannot happen.**
3. **You can capture the ships.** "If the land area connected to a Port is successfully attacked and taken control of by another player, that player may immediately replace any enemy Ship units in the Port with an equal number of his own available Ship units (or as many Ship units as he has available, he desires, or is allowed by supply limits). Excess enemy ships are simply removed from the board." (p. 25)

Comment: Further to sitnaltax's very good answer, I'm pretty concerned by the line "an empty one, not carrying land units" - Ships do not (and cannot) "carry" any units.

Ship Transport simply creates the effect of making land areas considered adjacent when connected by one or more sea areas containing your ships.

Comment: Thanks for answering. What I found confusing (at least in the version I have) is that information about port/ships is scattered in various pages.

Comment: In addition to the comment of @DanielLim: and these areas are only considered "adjacent" in the case of friendly (wrt. to the ships) MARCH orders... so no raid, support or card effect count through ships.

Comment: So, If I conquer a sea area that has connection to the port, I immediately replace the port ships? I was playing one round, there was 3 ships in the port, but I had the sea connected to it, and the player had been fighting me using port ships ( moving them to the sea and inducing the fight ). it was wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to capture the land that the port is connected to, to do that, you would need to capture the sea area connected to the port with your ships and then capture the land by transporting land units over